# Problema ao apresentar data no QTablewidget no python com PyQt5

Tags: mysql, python, data

Tenho um programa que mostra informações sobre produtos e queria apresentar a data, só que quando aparece a data, é isto que mostra: `PyQt5.QtCore.QDate(2018, 7, 7)`.

Para quem precisar esta aqui o código:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QTableWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QTime, QDateTime, Qt
from adicionar_produtos import Ui_adicionar

class Ui_Produtos(object):

# Adicionar
 def add(self):
    self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_adicionar()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()
#MainWindow
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    #MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920,510))
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
    self.btn_add = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.btn_add.setObjectName("btn_add")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_add)
    #-----------------------------
    """
    self.btn_edit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.btn_edit.setObjectName("btn_edit")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_edit)
    """
    #---------------------------------------
    self.btn_del = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.btn_del.setObjectName("btn_del")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_del)
    spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(998, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
    """
    self.btn_stock = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.btn_stock.setObjectName("btn_stock")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_stock)
    spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(150, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
    """
    #---------------------------------------------------
    """
    self.btn_cat = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.btn_cat.setObjectName("btn_cat")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_cat)
    """
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.tablep = QTableWidget()
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tablep)
    self.produtos()
    header = self.tablep.horizontalHeader()
    header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(3, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(4, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(5, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(6, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(7, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(8, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    #-------------------------------------------------------
    self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 783, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    self.menuFicheirp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menuFicheirp.setObjectName("menuFicheirp")
    self.menuExibir = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menuExibir.setObjectName("menuExibir")
    self.menuAjuda = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menuAjuda.setObjectName("menuAjuda")
    self.menuSobre = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuAjuda)
    self.menuSobre.setObjectName("menuSobre")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.actionExportar = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionExportar.setObjectName("actionExportar")
    self.actionFechar_Janela = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionFechar_Janela.setObjectName("actionFechar_Janela")
    self.actionSair = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionSair.setObjectName("actionSair")
    self.actionComo_Utilizar = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionComo_Utilizar.setObjectName("actionComo_Utilizar")
    self.actionCriador = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionCriador.setObjectName("actionCriador")
    self.menuFicheirp.addAction(self.actionExportar)
    self.menuFicheirp.addSeparator()
    self.menuFicheirp.addAction(self.actionFechar_Janela)
    self.menuFicheirp.addAction(self.actionSair)
    self.menuSobre.addAction(self.actionCriador)
    self.menuAjuda.addAction(self.actionComo_Utilizar)
    self.menuAjuda.addSeparator()
    self.menuAjuda.addAction(self.menuSobre.menuAction())
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFicheirp.menuAction())
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menuExibir.menuAction())
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAjuda.menuAction())

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    self.tablep.itemChanged.connect(self.editar)
    self.btn_add.clicked.connect(self.add)
    self.btn_del.clicked.connect(self.eliminar)


    #ler produtos
def produtos(self):
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
    db.setHostName("localhost")
    db.setDatabaseName("stock")
    db.setUserName("root")
    db.setPassword("")
    estado = db.open()
    print(estado)
    if estado == False:
       msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
       msgBox.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Warning)
       msgBox.setWindowTitle("Erro")
       msgBox.setText(db.lastError().text())
       msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
       msgBox.exec_()
    else:
       self.tablep.setColumnCount(9)
       self.tablep.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Nome', 'Descrição', 'Marca', 'Nível de Stock', 'Stock Fora?', 'Data de Reabastecimento', 'Preço', 'Validade'])
       row = 0
       sql = "SELECT ID, Nome, Descrição, marca, stock_nivel, stock_fora, dat_reabast, preco, validade FROM produtos"
       query = QSqlQuery(sql)
       while query.next():
             self.tablep.insertRow(row)
             ID = QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(0)))
             nome = QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(1)))
             Descricao = QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(2)))
             Marca = QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(3)))
             Stock_nivel = QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(4)))
             Stock_fora = QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(5)))
             dat_reabas = QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(6)))
             preco = QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(7)))
             Validade = QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(8)))
             self.tablep.setItem(row, 0, ID)
             self.tablep.setItem(row, 1, nome)
             self.tablep.setItem(row, 2, Descricao)
             self.tablep.setItem(row, 3, Marca)
             self.tablep.setItem(row, 4, Stock_nivel)
             self.tablep.setItem(row, 5, Stock_fora)
             self.tablep.setItem(row, 6, dat_reabas)
             self.tablep.setItem(row, 7, preco)
             self.tablep.setItem(row, 8, Validade)
             row = row + 1
    db.close()
def eliminar(self):
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
    db.setHostName("localhost")
    db.setDatabaseName("stock")
    db.setUserName("root")
    db.setPassword("")
    estado = db.open()
    if estado == False:
       msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
       msgBox.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Warning)
       msgBox.setWindowTitle("Erro")
       msgBox.setText(db.lastError().text())
       msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
       msgBox.exec_()
    else:
        rows = self.tablep.selectionModel().selectedRows()
        index = []
        for i in rows:
            index.append(i.row())
            index.sort(reverse=True)
            for i in index:
                ID = self.tablep.item(i, 0).text()
                self.tablep.removeRow(i)
                sql = "DELETE FROM produtos WHERE ID=:id"
                query = QSqlQuery()
                query.prepare(sql)
                query.bindValue(":id", ID)
                estado = query.exec_()
                if estado == False:
                     msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
                     msgBox.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Warning)
                     msgBox.setWindowTitle("Erro")
                     msgBox.setText(db.lastError().text())
                     msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Discard)
                     msgBox.exec_()
    db.close()


def editar(self):
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
    db.setHostName("localhost")
    db.setDatabaseName("stock")
    db.setUserName("root")
    db.setPassword("")
    estado = db.open()
    if estado == False:
        msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Warning)
        msgBox.setWindowTitle("Erro")
        msgBox.setText(db.lastError().text())
        msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgBox.exec_()
    else:
        column = self.tablep.currentColumn()
        row = self.tablep.currentRow()
        ID = self.tablep.item(row, 0).text()
        value = self.tablep.currentItem().text()
        columns = ['ID', 'Nome', 'Descrição', 'Marca', 'Nível de Stock', 'Stock Fora?', 'Data de Reabastecimento', 'Preço', 'Validade']
        query = QSqlQuery()
        sql = "UPDATE produtos SET " + columns[column] + "=" + ":value WHERE ID=:id"
        query.prepare(sql)
        query.bindValue(":id", ID)
        query.bindValue(":value", value)
        estado = query.exec_()
        if estado == False:
            msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Warning)
            msgBox.setWindowTitle("Erro")
            msgBox.setText(db.lastError().text())
            msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Discard)
            msgBox.exec_()
    db.close()

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Produtos"))
    self.btn_add.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Adicionar"))
    #self.btn_edit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Editar"))
    self.btn_del.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Eliminar"))
    #self.btn_stock.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stock"))
    #self.btn_cat.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Categorias"))
    self.menuFicheirp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Ficheiro"))
    self.menuExibir.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Exibir"))
    self.menuAjuda.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Ajuda"))
    self.menuSobre.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Sobre"))
    self.actionExportar.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exportar"))
    self.actionFechar_Janela.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Fechar Janela"))
    self.actionSair.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sair"))
    self.actionComo_Utilizar.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Como Utilizar"))
    self.actionCriador.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Criador"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Ui_Produtos()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o `toString()` para exibir.

**Ex**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

# Exibindo a data que foi passada para o QDate().
print(QDate(2018, 7, 7).toString())
```

O `toString()` também permite a formatação da data, para isso:

- **d**:       Os dias sem zero (1 até 31).
- **dd**:      Os dias com zero (01 até 31).
- **ddd**:     Nome do dia abreviado (Ex: 'Seg', 'Dom').
- **dddd**:    Nome do dia completo (Ex: 'Segunda' to 'Domingo').
- **M**:       O mês sem zero (1 até 12).
- **MM**:      O mês com zero (01 até 12).
- **MMM**:     Nome do mês abreviado (Ex: 'Jan', 'Dez').
- **MMMM**:    Nome do mês completo (Ex: 'Janeiro', 'Dezembro').
- **yy**:      Ano com 2 dígitos (00 até 99).
- **yyyy**:    Ano com 4 dígitos.

**Ex**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

# Formatando a exibição.
print(QDate(2018, 7, 7).toString('dd/MM/yyyy'))
print(QDate(2018, 7, 7).toString('ddd d MMMM yy'))
print('Hoje é:', QDate(2018, 7, 7).toString('dddd'))
```

Dependendo da situação você pode utilizar:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

# Formatadores prontos.
print('Dia:', QDate(2018, 7, 7).day())
print('Mês:', QDate(2018, 7, 7).month())
print('Ano:', QDate(2018, 7, 7).year())
```